# New axios request in response

Tags: vue.js, axios

I'm posting to an API using axios, and using the data from the response I want to make another API request but I'm running into issues saying that `axios is not defined`.

The calls, that are in inside my Vue login component, are the following:

```js
this.axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: '/my_api/test',
  data: "testdata=test123",
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  }
})

.then(function (response) {
  this.axios({
    method: 'get',
    url: '/my_api/test2',
    data: "testdata2=" + response.data.id
  })
})
```

and as I mentioned earlier, the error in my console is the following: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'axios' of undefined`.

I´ve tried writing the second request without `this.` but I'm having the same issues. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) here.

Regular functions have their own `this` value.

```js
this.axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: '/my_api/test',
  data: "testdata=test123",
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  }
})

.then(response => {
  this.axios({
    method: 'get',
    url: '/my_api/test2',
    data: "testdata2=" + response.data.id
  })
})
```

Or if you prefer old-fashioned way you can save `this` reference to some variable to have access to it in the callback:

```js
const self = this

this.axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: '/my_api/test',
  data: "testdata=test123",
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  }
})

.then(function (response) {
  self.axios({
    method: 'get',
    url: '/my_api/test2',
    data: "testdata2=" + response.data.id
  })
})
```